# What is the meaning of "T-up opportunity"?

Tags: word-meaning

I come across the following words in a mail:

```
......  
Sorry for late reply which partially due to interviews for a potential T-up opportunity.  
......
```

What is the meaning of `T-up opportunity` here? I can't find explanations from google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> T-up (tee up)

is an expression taken from golfing

[image]

it means **to setup** the golf ball to be ready for the first hit towards the hole.

The writer in your example is saying they had some interviews which was **setting them up** for a possible job opportunity.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't "tie-up"?

Comment: @user3169 - Neither expression is very familiar to me, but "tee up" is at least a known phrase.  What does "tie-up opportunity" mean?

Comment: A [*tie-up*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/tie-up): "2. *countable noun* - A tie-up between two organizations is a business connection that has been arranged between them." The context is vague, but it seemed like a possibility.

Comment: Interesting!  I had never heard that one before.  Thanks for educating me!